# Data is not binding properly to the bean in form input display tag

Tags: spring, tags, display

```
<display:table name="command.stationList" class="displaytag" id="row">
<display:column title="Short">
<form:input path="stationList[${row_rowNum-1}].shortName"/>
<form:input path="stationList[${row_rowNum-1}].shortName"/>
</display:column>
</display:table>
```

In above code ,short name is not getting updated to its right index rather it is getting assigned randomly to other rows after save the page. can you please tell me what is causing the issue and how to fix this.

Comment: Information supplied is not enough to answer your question. Add more codes

Comment: The below piece of code 
<form:input path="stationList[${row_rowNum-1}].shortName"/>
is not binding the shortname to its corresponding index of the list. Please let me know what more information are you looking for.